# Homework help, invalid parameters binary trees

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I have a problem with my homework.  Oddly, the function of treeHeight works.  It was provided by the book.  I made nodeCount and leavesCount for this homework and get these build errors for it when the one the author made doesn't

The build error:

```
1>  testProgBinarySearchTree.cpp
1>testProgBinarySearchTree.cpp(49): error C2660: 'binaryTreeType<elemType>::nodeCount'     : function does not take 0 arguments
1>          with
1>          [
1>              elemType=int
1>          ]
1>testProgBinarySearchTree.cpp(50): error C2660: 'binaryTreeType<elemType>::leavesCount' : function does not take 0 arguments
1>          with
1>          [
1>              elemType=int
1>          ]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The source code main:

```
cout << endl<<"Line 24: Tree Height: "
     << treeRoot.treeHeight() << endl;              //Line 24

cout << endl << "The node count is: " << treeRoot.nodeCount();
cout << endl << "The leaf count is: " << treeRoot.leavesCount();
```

Class :

```
int height(binaryTreeNode<elemType> *p) const;
  //Function to return the height of the binary tree
  //to which p points. 
int max(int x, int y) const;
  //Returns the larger of x and y.
int nodeCount(binaryTreeNode<elemType> *p) const;
  //Function to return the number of nodes in the binary 
  //tree to which p points 
int leavesCount(binaryTreeNode<elemType> *p) const;
  //Function to return the number of leaves in the binary 
  //tree to which p points 

template <class elemType>
int binaryTreeType<elemType>::height(binaryTreeNode<elemType> *p) const
{
    if (p == NULL)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1 + max(height(p->llink), height(p->rlink));
}

template <class elemType>
int binaryTreeType<elemType>::max(int x, int y) const
{
    if (x >= y)
        return x;
    else
        return y;
}

template <class elemType>
int binaryTreeType<elemType>::nodeCount(binaryTreeNode<elemType> *p) const
{
    if (p == null)
    return 0;
else
    return nodeCount(p->llink) + nodeCount(p->rlink) + 1;
}

template <class elemType>
int binaryTreeType<elemType>::leavesCount(binaryTreeNode<elemType> *p) const
{
    if (p == null)
    return 0;
else
    if ( leavesCount(p->llink) == 0 && leavesCount(p->rlink) == 0)
        return 1;
    else 
        return leavesCount(p->llink) + leavesCount (p->rlink); 
}
```

FIGURE IT OUT THANKS.
Another function calls this with similar names and I missed it, fixed and thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you *precisely* what the problem is; those functions require arguments.  You are calling them without arguments.

Comment: @user1044754: Where is the author calling them without arguments?

Comment: Thanks figured it out, the author made two similar functions to input the root, I found those function for the others.

Comment: Figured it out another function calls this with root

Answer (score 1):

```
int binaryTreeType<elemType>::nodeCount(binaryTreeNode<elemType> *p) const

cout << endl << "The node count is: " << treeRoot.nodeCount();
```

Your error says that `nodeCount` doesn't take zero arguments. From your function signature, you need to pass in a `binaryTreeNode<elemType> *p`, and the way you are calling it is not passing anything in.

From the code, it looks like you should be passing the root node in.

Comment: I don't see treeHeight defined anywhere up there